# Android and website synchronization

Tags: android

I have an issue. We have a website, where person can login and make it`s own list`s of news. Now we trying to develop an Android application, where person could login and do the same in phone. I cannot understand best preactises of implementing such things. It have to be same accounts, with same preserved data as stored online on website.

Could anyone tell me how to synchronize web and android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use backend scripts to get the same data from database of website in android. You need to call a script(in any language like php) to get the data from database. and show this in listview in android or compare it with the user id password entered.

Comment: The point is that if for instance User1 came and see his list, then User 2 came and he has different list of information on webiste. How to achieve the same in mobile application?

Comment: For your website purpose you must have a database somewhere with list in it corresponding to users. In the same way, if a user with id and password logins and you call a script to check whether this user exists, and after that get the list of that user using sqlite query in your scripts.   I have  done a similar website and android app having similar data , So I can assure you that this is possible in a very simple way. Do you need any more help?

Comment: Yes, please. How you send passord and login? Is it just an ordinary post? Or maybe some tools exist regarding this issue. And one more question. When you load database from website to mobile device it is clear that it will be changed on website. How to update it? Clean out all old data and add new ones? In this occasion most of datas will be dublicated. Maybe some tool exist to add just new datas not removing old ones?

Comment: you can normally create textview with id and password. Get the text of these two fields and call a script and send these two values to it. On the server side(i.e in script) you make a sqlite query for checking these values with id-password tables values. And if it matches any of those, return yes. This is how we know about existannce of id-password

Comment: which second question?Kindly ask again. If my comments are helpful to you please upvote.

Comment: When you load database from website to mobile device it is clear that it will be changed on website. How to update it? Clean out all old data and add new ones? In this occasion most of datas will be dublicated. Maybe some tool exist to add just new datas not removing old ones?

Comment: No data will be removed in this way. I think, you should consult your backend script developer. Sqlite queries can work in any way we want it. It will add data, update from your app too. And I think that it is working the same from your website. There is nothing like tool. Don't worry